# From Synapse RF Engine to PIC

Tags: pic, piezoelectricity

I made a little program on my [Synapse RF Engine](http://www.synapse-wireless.com/modules) to detect some vibrations and then turn on a light basically.

What I want to know is how do I get this prototype to an actual PIC that I can connect the piezo sensor, led lights and power source? How do you choose a PIC? And is this the way to do this? The programming is super simple, just reading the digital output of the piezo sensor and then based on that turn the light on or not.

Comment: Which module did you use specifically? Different ones have very different CPUs on them. What language and development system did you use to write your program? All of this is important context required to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: Hi Dave, I have the EK2100 kit. and I used Python to do it

Answer (score 1):

Micrchip has a interactive selector guide for PICs.  You select ranges of parameters you care about, and it lists the PICs that meet the criteria sorted by price or another parameter of your choosing.  I think it's called "MAPS".  Look around on their site.  I think it will be easy to find.

If all you want to do is turn on a light based on a digital output, you don't need a microcontroller.  Some digital outputs have enough current capability to drive LEDs directly, or you can use a transistor and one or two resistors to drive a LED from any digital output.

Comment: http://www.microchip.com/maps/microcontroller.aspx

Comment: Ok, let me try building that on my breadboard first and see how it goes. thanks

Comment: I thought something as simple as this pic would be good enough? PIC12F675